# Unity animated ribbon effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

Could tell me how to make these yellow animated ribbons like the ones seen in this video were made? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9dtp2PSrPg

Is it made using a particle system? Or do you think it was made outside of Unity?

I'd love some direction on how I could recreate this effect. (I'm quite new to Unity so any help is appreciated)

Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: as Tiziano explains this has ***nothing to do with Unity***  Unity simply is just not for making 2D graphics. it's absolutely trivial to do this in photoshop or the like, but it's just "not something you can do" in Unity.  it would be rather like asking "how to animate a first person shooter in photoshop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiziano is right. You can use Procedural but I think that is complicated. If you are advanced then you can do that.

There is an easier way to do this like you asked. It is called [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html)
You need to learn Coroutine first, then animate the `LineRenderer` by moving the position of the LineRenderer's points in coroutine. This is the easiest way of doing this in unity.

If you look at the video below at **0**:**27**, you will see what `LineRenderer` can do.
https://youtu.be/9hE7-rGg7Tg?t=27

Learn about animating with `LineRenderer`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqcu94VuVOI

Answer (score 1):

If it is for a video, go for Adobe After Effects + Trapcode Particular:
https://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-particular/

In Unity: waaay more difficult. Probably procedural spline-based mesh generation. You need to know lot of stuff about bezier curves, 3d meshes, what exactly is a vertex in a 3d model and other strange things.

And everything it's explained quite well here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9RK6O2kOKo

P.S. @Night.owl You owe me two beers, mate :) ahahaha

Comment: Yes I was wanting to make this for a game in Unity, but this is way more complicated than I thought. Looks like i'll have to find an easier alternative! 

Hehe i'm just a beginner,  appreciate the help!